# find and save percentage of two columns in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have $a and $b colons in mongodb. I want to do the following in $c column with PHP.

$number = $a/$b * (100-100);

That is, I want to find the percentage change and save it in column $c.

can you help me?

{
"a": 0.16,
"b": 0.15,
"c: ?
},

Comment: Surely the result of your formula `$number = $a/$b * (100-100);` will always be zero? It'll evaluate the division first, and then multiply the result by (100-100), which is zero, and anything multiplied by zero is zero. Or is that a typo in your post?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: db.orantakip.update({}, {$set: {damista:{"$multiply":[{"$divide":["$giriskur","$gelenkur"]}, 100]}}} , {multi: true});

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - as you can see, it's unreadable. Edit your question to include any code samples.